# VGA slight flickering/wavy pattern on dark colors

Tags: display, vga, analog

I have a vga monitor attached to my laptop. Whenever I am displaying darker colors, there is a sort of wavy flickering (not seizure inducing, but smooth flickering). It is also more profound when I am moving my cursor or displaying moving contents. It is not there when displaying lighter colors (like this site). The monitor doesn't flicker like this when it is attached to my desktop. Could this be interference because it is an analog signal? if so how does this come about?